# Php Form Submit without Refresh - Ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to get get my form to submit without having the page refreshing everytime

However, when I insert the ajax and place the php into a new file the form doesnt submit and I dont understand why?

Any advice would be appreicated!

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['message'])){
    //Post data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    //mail settings
    $to = "arshdsoni@gmail.com";
    $subject = 'Soni Repairs - Support Request';
    $body = <<<EMAIL

Hi There!

My name is $name.

Message: $message.

My email is: $email
Phone Number: $phone

Kind Regards
EMAIL;

    $header = "From: $email";

    if($_POST) {
        if($name == '' || $email == '' || $phone == '' || $message == '') {
            echo $feedback = "<font color='red'> *Please Fill in All Fields!";
        }
        else {
            mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
            echo $feedback = "<font color='green'> *Message sent! You will receive a reply shortly!";
        }
    }

}

else{
    echo $feedback = "<font color='red'> Missing Params";
}

?>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#submitBtn").click(function( event ) {
                    //values
                    var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
                    var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
                    var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
                    var occasion=document.getElementById('occasion').value;
                    var dataString = $("#contact").serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"php.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(html) {
                            $('#feedback').html(html);
                        }
                    });
                  event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**HTML CODE HERE: http://www.codeply.com/go/e3jAo1WrPl**

Comment: What happens? Do you get any errors in your browser console? Does the `success` callback execute?

Comment: where is your `<div id="feedback"></div>` ?

Comment: @shehary - The div id=feedback is in the form - This code works in my previous site but not in my new one which is really weird

Comment: @showdev - nothing happens it doesnt seem to even submit - I click submit but nothing sends, the info is still there

Comment: Please post the HTML.

Comment: @abalter - HTML code added above

Comment: Could it be because your form id is `contactForm`, not `contact`? Add a fail method to the ajax call to confirm that the ajax is running, but the query is failing.

Comment: @abalter - I had my form named to contact before and then i changed it but it still isnt working

Answer (score 0):

The .bind() function may be the way to go with this form, since it binds the action of clicking the button to the event handler.

It also may be beneficial to have the event.preventDefault() before your ajax call.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submitBtn").bind([boundElement],function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
                var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
                var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
                var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
                var occasion=document.getElementById('occasion').value;
                var dataString = $("#contact").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"php.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#feedback').html(html);
                    }
                });
             return true;
            });
        });
```

I would recommend double-checking the syntax for the bound element in the .bind() parameters. It is single quote marks for referring to a named form element
Example HTML:

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion with using a button in stead of a submit. I commented out the `preventDefault`, because it is unnecessary in this case -- we are not actually submitting the form. This gives us more control.

The request is submitted. In this case, it obviously fails. In your case, whether or not it fails is going to depend on what you have going on server side.

http://plnkr.co/edit/txuxaFUkgFq9SFDcqUdp

```
<form action="http://www.yahoo.com" id="contactForm" method="get" target="_blank">
    <div class="innerForm">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" />
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
        <label for="occasion">Occasion:</label>
        <input id="occasion" type="text" name="occasion" />
        <label id="messageLabel" for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        <button id="test">test</button>
        <!--input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" name="submit" onclick="return chk();"/ -->
    </div>
    <div id="feedback"></div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function (event) {
      //values
      alert("test clicked");
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
      var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
      var occasion = document.getElementById('occasion').value;
      var dataString = $("#contactForm").serialize();

      $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "http://www.yahoo.com",
          data: dataString,
          success: function (html) {
              alert("success");
              //$('#feedback').html(html);
          },
          error: function(result){
              alert("failure");
          }
      });
      //event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var name       = $('#name').val(),
            email      = $('#email').val(),
            phone      = $('#phone').val(),
            message    = $('#message').val(),
            occasion   = $('#occasion').val(),
            dataString = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: dataString,
        })
        .done( function( html ) {
            $( '#feedback' ).html( html );
        })
        .fail( function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
        });

    });
});
```

Firs of all, you have the form and the submit button, so when you press the button, the event 'submit' is triggered, so you prevent the event to be fired, then you do your coding, the variables, but I cannot understand why you declare all those, if you don't use them, but that's up to you.